# Using a pl/sql procedure to log errors and handle exceptions

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, error-handling

so far stack overflow and the oracle forums and docs have been my best friend in learning PLSQL. I'm running into an issue here. Any advice is appreciated. I'm writing a procedure that would be used to log any errors a package may encounter and log them into the error log table I created. here is my code thus far.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE APMS.test_procedure AS

    procedure write_error_log (errcode number, errstr varchar2, errline varchar2) is
    pragma autonomous_transaction; 
    -- this procedure stays in its own new private transaction
    begin                         
          INSERT INTO error_log
               (ora_err_tmsp,
                      ora_err_number,
                      ora_err_msg,
                      ora_err_line_no)
          values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                  errcode,
                  errstr,
                  errline);
          COMMIT;  -- this commit does not interfere with the caller's transaction.
    end write_error_log;

 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO mockdata
        VALUES ('data1', 'mockname', 'mockcity'); 

  exception when others then             
    write_error_log(sqlcode,sqlerrm,dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
    raise; 
 END test_procedure;
/
```

In the procedure I currently am using a mockdata table to induce an invalid number error and log that to the error_log table. At this point the error log table proves to be functional and inserts the data needed. The next step for me is to use this procedure to be used in the exception handlers in other programs so that the error is caught and logged to the table. Currently, my procedure is only unique to the mock_data table. My mentor/superior is telling me I need to pass this program some parameters to use it in other packages and exception handlers. I'm just having a bit of trouble. Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Comment: I think your procedure can be used to log an error in any scenario where mock_data table exists. You can call it from any package or exception handler to log the error. Sorry, maybe i don't understand very well your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm trying to remove the mock_data table and use this procedure for other packages and procedures in the schema to log those errors. The mock_data table was purely for testing purposes. Also, I'm pretty sure you helped me on my last question haha so thanks for being so helpful

Comment: `write_error_log` should be defined as a separate procedure not defined as a nested procedure within `test_procedure`.  I'd create a package that has the `write_error_log` procedure along with whatever other logging related procedures you need.  You could then call the `error_log.write_error_log` procedure throughout your code.

Comment: Yes, but you should have a table where all these errors will be stored, or you want to do this passing the table name as a procedure parameter?

Comment: I have an error_log table where the errors will be stored. The table is indicated in the code above its called error_log.

Comment: Well, as @JustinCave said before, first you should create a package with your `write_error_log` procedure. Then you can call it from any exception handler, see that your procedure parameters depends of the kind of exception thrown.

Comment: Thank you to both of you im learning so much. Do you have any points of research I should look into to study procedure parameters?

Comment: Maybe I did not explain well. The parameters that are using in your procedure are correct, they vary depending on the exception you're handling. For example when an invalid number exception is thrown you get a different message if an exception of constraint was raised. You just have to put the call to your procedure within the exception block you want to handle. I hope you understand what i'm trying to say

Answer (score 2):

Steven Feuerstein has written several articles in Oracle Magazine on how to handle errors in PLSQL. He offers a small framework (errpkg) for doing this. The DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself) is his mantra!

https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/0636920024859/blob/master/errpkg.pkg

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: @Toolkit I found a reference to the errpkg in Stevens Book "Oracle PLSQL Programming 6th Edition"

Answer (score 1):

First, you should *not* make your caller pass in `errline`.  That's very tedious!  And what happens when the developer needs to insert a line or two of code?  Do they need to update every call to `write_error_log` after that point to update the line numbers?  Your `write_error_log` should use `dbms_utility.format_call_stack` (or the 12c more convenient variant of that.. don't have its name handy) to figure out what line of code issued the call to `write_error_log`.

Then, you should have a 2nd procedure called, say, `write_exception`.  All that needs to do is something like this:

```
write_error_log (SQLCODE, SUBSTR (DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack || DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace, 1, 4000));
```

Comment: I don't understand the `errline` part very well, the developer only needs to pass DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace to get the line error(`write_error_log(sqlcode,sqlerrm,dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace)`), they don't need to update if add a line or two. I think could be a good idea use DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack to get the full error message

Comment: If *all* you want to be able to log are SQL exceptions, then you don't need to accept any parameters at all.  Your logging procedure can call DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK / BACKTRACE and be done with it.

Comment: Yes, you're right, you don't need to set it as a parameter, you can call directly from the procedure.